# Heavyweight component in Swing JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to put the chromium browser in a JInternalFrame. I am using the [jcef](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef) Framework. The problem is that i get a heavyweight awt component from the framework, which makes problems that looks similar to [that](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/digitalasset/434001.png). Now I have found [an article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) where it is described that the bug should be fixed in Java 7, with some limitations.
The problem is that I have a use case of a limitation in the article:

> - Embedded heavyweight components must belong to the process that created the frame or applet. The heavyweight component must have a valid peer within the main process of the application (or applet).

The jcef-framework creates the component in a extra process. Does someone has an idea for a workaround?

Comment: The long and short answer is - no. Even though it's been suggested that mixing heavy weight components with light weight components have been fixed in recent versions, I've never had any real success in doing so. JavaFX might be the closet you can get t a native web browser in Java

Comment: Hi, Any success on using Heavyweight component inside JinternalFrame?, as i am also having the same issue.